# Sort the JSON based on field value and replace null with '-'

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json response which I want  to sort(A-z) the json based on number field .I have null value in json response I want to replace all the occurance of 'null' with '-'.In reason and sub reason I want to displaying 'null'.need to replace it with '-'

```js
const result={
   "response":{
      "data":[
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "customeraccounttype":"Existing Customer",
            "expectedclosuredate":"31-Jan-2020",
            "datecreated":"15-Jan-2020",
            "datemodified":"03-Apr-2020",
            "salesstagelastmodified":"03-Apr-2020",
            "reason":null,
            "sub_reason":null
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Akhil Pal",
            "customeraccounttype":"New Customer",
            "expectedclosuredate":"29-Nov-2019",
            "datecreated":"01-Aug-2019",
            "datemodified":"04-Apr-2020",
            "salesstagelastmodified":"04-Apr-2020",
            "reason":null,
            "sub_reason":null
         },
         {
            "UserName":"bala Shanmugam",
            "customeraccounttype":"New Customer",
            "expectedclosuredate":"30-Sep-2019",
            "datecreated":"01-Aug-2019",
            "datemodified":"05-Apr-2020",
            "salesstagelastmodified":"05-Apr-2020",
            "reason":null,
            "sub_reason":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
function GetSortOrder(prop) {    
    return function(a, b) {    
        if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {    
            return 1;    
        } else if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {    
            return -1;    
        }    
        return 0;    
    }    
}   
result.sort(GetSortOrder("UserName"));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm geeting sort is not a function error

Comment: _"based on number field"_? Sorry, what field do you want to use for sorting?

Comment: I want to sotrt based on 'UserName' field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sorting strings, your current method looks ok but I'd recommend [`String.prototype.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

The more complex operation is replacing any `null` values. Personally, I'd just do that in the UI but to answer your question, something like this

```js
const result = {"response":{"data":[{"UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju","customeraccounttype":"Existing Customer","expectedclosuredate":"31-Jan-2020","datecreated":"15-Jan-2020","datemodified":"03-Apr-2020","salesstagelastmodified":"03-Apr-2020","reason":null,"sub_reason":null},{"UserName":"Akhil Pal","customeraccounttype":"New Customer","expectedclosuredate":"29-Nov-2019","datecreated":"01-Aug-2019","datemodified":"04-Apr-2020","salesstagelastmodified":"04-Apr-2020","reason":null,"sub_reason":null},{"UserName":"bala Shanmugam","customeraccounttype":"New Customer","expectedclosuredate":"30-Sep-2019","datecreated":"01-Aug-2019","datemodified":"05-Apr-2020","salesstagelastmodified":"05-Apr-2020","reason":null,"sub_reason":null}]}}

// start with the actual data
const data = result.response.data

// map nulls to "-"
const mapped = data.map(r => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(r).map(([ key, val ]) =>
  [ key, val ?? "-" ])))

// sort
mapped.sort((a, b) => a.UserName.localeCompare(b.UserName))

console.info(mapped)
```

This maps your existing array to a new one where *nullish* values are replaced with `-`.

See

- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `replace` function to have your `null` replaced by `"-"`

You need to use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.Stringify` and look for nulls and replace with whatever you would like.

Run snippet below.

```js
const result = {
  "response": {
    "data": [{
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "customeraccounttype": "Existing Customer",
        "expectedclosuredate": "31-Jan-2020",
        "datecreated": "15-Jan-2020",
        "datemodified": "03-Apr-2020",
        "salesstagelastmodified": "03-Apr-2020",
        "reason": null,
        "sub_reason": null
      },
      {
        "UserName": "Akhil Pal",
        "customeraccounttype": "New Customer",
        "expectedclosuredate": "29-Nov-2019",
        "datecreated": "01-Aug-2019",
        "datemodified": "04-Apr-2020",
        "salesstagelastmodified": "04-Apr-2020",
        "reason": null,
        "sub_reason": null
      },
      {
        "UserName": "bala Shanmugam",
        "customeraccounttype": "New Customer",
        "expectedclosuredate": "30-Sep-2019",
        "datecreated": "01-Aug-2019",
        "datemodified": "05-Apr-2020",
        "salesstagelastmodified": "05-Apr-2020",
        "reason": null,
        "sub_reason": null
      }
    ]
  }
}

const replaceNull = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result).replace(/null/g, '"-"'))
console.log(replaceNull)
```

Comment: Using the `JSON.parse` _reviver_ might be a safer bet than string manipulation. Very creative though